# Is there a way I can create a unique Id for a table inserted with a stored proc without using Identity

Tags: sql-server

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId]  INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    ....
```

When my application makes a copy of a test so it is available to a user it uses a stored procedure to do this. Here's a shortened version of what I have inside that stored procedure.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
 (Title, ....)

SELECT  Title, ....
FROM    Test
WHERE   TestId = @TestId;
```

So then for example a table with a TestId of 200 
may have a copy made with a TestId of 225 or whatever number comes next in the identity sequence.

I would like to make it so that I now have control over creating the TestId. I would still like it to be unique of course but for copies I want something like a TestId of 200 to become 200-1 when copied.

Can someone give me a suggestion
as to how I can generate a unique number for the TestId inside my stored procedure **instead of my using identity**. I know
Oracle has sequences but is there anything like this with SQL Server and how could I use
them in a stored procedure?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're hopeing to accomplish - you want a unique value without using an identity, but you want to have control over the value.  First you could set your identity column as primary key to enforce uniqueness - but this will cause errors if your SP tries to create a record with an entry where that identity already exists.  You can turn identity insert off for inserts, but again if you attempt to insert the row (and the row is a primary key) you'll get a constraint error

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has sequences (starting with sql 2012).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

You could also use an identity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do what you suggest as your desired solution. This is probably a better solution.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
   TestID int identity(1,1) not null
,  OriginalID int not null
,  MoreStuff ...

   primary key (NewID)
)
```

You probably want an index on OriginalID too

And in your proc

```
Insert Into TEST (OrginalID, MoreStuff ...)
select TestID, MoreStuff ..
from Test from where TestID = @ID
```

Now you have a new test based on the original. And you can still refer back to the original based on OriginalID.

ADDED

This avoids somewhat messy logic that would be needed for you original suggestion. Now, if you must have a sequence 1,2,3 for each "based" test case, you can of course following your original suggestion (or a separate column for the inner sequence number). But don't do this unless you are forced to do so.